# How to reset sound and bluetooth settings on Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

When I was using Ubuntu 12.04, sound with a Bluetooth headset worked perfectly. After turning on the headset, it would autoconnect and the sound manager would automatically switch to it in high-fidelity mode so I could listen to music through it. I had to make some minor adjustments to my /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf, but that was it.

However, after I upgraded to Ubuntu 14, it all stopped working. I have basic sound, but bluetooth will no longer autoconnect and often it will refuse to connect at all. Even after I manage to manually initiate the connection to my headset, the Sound settings dialog still won't list it as an output option.

At this point, I'm not sure if the problem is that Ubuntu 14.04 just has buggier bluetooth+sound support for my now much older computer, or if there's a conflict between the newer libraries and my older configuration settings. To rule out the later, how should I "reset" my local sound and bluetooth configuration and start from scratch?

Is it enough to just do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure bluez
sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-sound-base
```

or should I do something else instead?

Edit: Addeded terminal output.

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1241:1037 Belkin 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Linux aeson 3.13.0-55-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 18 00:27:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[   14.209278] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   14.209317] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.209655] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.209657] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.209661] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.663231] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   22.663241] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   22.663245] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   22.794109] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.794113] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.794120] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Post the result of `lsusb; uname -a; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep firmware` by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/640600/edit) your question to add the info.

Comment: @Jeremy31, I've updated my question.

Comment: what is the result from `pactl list short`